# Question about compiling sources code with HDF5 and mpi

Tags: linux, mpi, gfortran, hdf5, fftw

When I am trying to compile the source code by 'make', the first steps that creating the '.o' files are running fine, and all '.o' files could be compiled normally. However, when compiling the executable file:

```
mpifort -fopenmp -O3 -o MyEXE sth.o main.o -L/usr/local/share/fftw-3.3.8/lib -lfftw3_mpi -lfftw3 -lm -L/usr/local/share/mpich-3.2/lib -lmpi -lz -L/usr/local/share/hdf5-1.8.18/lib                                                                               -lhdf5_fortran -lhdf5hl_fortran -lhdf5_hl -lhdf5 -fPIC
```

it gots the following error:

```
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/local/share/hdf5-1.8.18/lib/libhdf5.a(H5PL.o): undefined reference to symbol 'dlclose@@GLIBC_2.2.5'
//lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2: error adding symbols: DSO missing from command line
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

How could I solve this problem? Some pages suggest that it is due to the '-ldl- flag when calling c++ compiler, but I couldn't find a way to make it suitable for my cases.

Answer (score 1):

The pages were right. Your HDF5 library *libhdf5.a* uses the function `dlclose`, which is defined in the library *libdl*. To use it, you need to simply add `-ldl` at the end of your `mpifort` command line.

Comment: Thank you so much, the problem seems to be fixed by adding the '-ldl' flag at the end.